# Flask. Как динамически задавать приглашения в форме

Tags: python, flask, forms

Делаю загрузку файлов, хотя это не важно. Вот обычный вариант работает:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import FileField, SubmitField, ValidationError  

class UploadForm(Form):
    xl_data_file = FileField('Задайте *.xls файл')
    submit = SubmitField('Отправить')
```

Все работает. Мне хочется на разных ветках использоватиь разные подсказки 'Задайте *.xls файл',  'Задайте *.doc файл', 'Задайте *.jpg файл'. Не подскажите как это сделать?

Я попробовал так:

```
class UploadForm(Form):
def __init__(self, text):
    self.xl_data_file = FileField(f'Задайте *.{text} файл')
    self.submit = SubmitField('Отправить')
```

При этом заменив где надо `form = UploadForm()` на `form = UploadForm(file)`. Но получил ошибку `AttributeError: 'UploadForm' object has no attribute '_fields'`  во время выполнения...
В нете про эту ошибку я за 15 минут ничего не нарыл (возможно потому что я новичек в Flask).
Итого два вопроса.
1) как получить желаемое
2) что это за ошибка
...
Конечно, я могу создать три класса.)
Видимо, необходимо запустить родной инит, так как я "переписал" его.
Вариант

```
class UploadForm(Form):
def __init__(self, text):
    super().__init__()
    self.xl_data_file = FileField('Задайте *.xls файл')
    self.submit = SubmitField('Отправить')
```

не выводит форму, а вариант

```
class UploadForm(Form):
def __init__(self, text):
    super().__init__(self)
    self.xl_data_file = FileField('Задайте *.xls файл')
    self.submit = SubmitField('Отправить')
```

выдает ошибку `AttributeError: 'UploadForm' object has no attribute 'getlist'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UploadForm(Form):
    # Поля обязательно нужно оставить среди переменных самого класса
    xl_data_file = FileField('Задайте *.xls файл')
    submit = SubmitField('Отправить')

    # Можно объявить свой init, но не объявлять в нем поля формы
    def __init__(self, text=None):
        super().__init__()
        if text:
            # А переопределить атрибут label у существующего поля
            self.xl_data_file.label.text = text
```

В коде обработчиков, перед тем, как отобразить шаблон:

```
form = UploadForm('Задайте *.doc файл')
# Даже так, если на ходу передумал, тогда и init не нужен
form.xl_data_file.label.text = 'Задайте *.ptt файл'
```

Comment: а можно ссылку на то, где почитать?
русский-английский все равно

Comment: Всегда ориентируюсь на документацию https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Label Также ответы на многие вопросы есть в английском SO, нередко ищу там. Например вот этот решает задачу https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398865/4710144 вероятно с `*args, **kwargs` даже лучше, потому что init у формы не обязательно без аргументов, просто у всех есть значение по-умолчанию, либо повторить сигнатуру https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/forms.html#the-form-class и брать данные из `kwargs`, это я не учел.